# What is meaning of a dataStreamId which looks like derived:com.google.activity.segment:<>:from_sample<-derived:com.google.activity.sample:<>:detailed

Tags: google-fit

I am new to google fit api. I was exploring my own fit account. I find this below data source id in my datasources.

Below is the exact dataSource

```
{
 "dataStreamId": "derived:com.google.activity.segment:com.google.android.gms:OnePlus:ONE A2003:10398c01:from_sample<-derived:com.google.activity.sample:com.google.android.gms:OnePlus:ONE A2003:10398c01:detailed",
 "dataStreamName": "from_sample<-derived:com.google.activity.sample:com.google.android.gms:OnePlus:ONE A2003:10398c01:detailed",
 "type": "derived",
 "dataType": {
  "name": "com.google.activity.segment",
  "field": [
   {
    "name": "activity",
    "format": "integer"
   }
  ]
 },
 "device": {
  "uid": "10398c01",
  "type": "phone",
  "version": "",
  "model": "ONE A2003",
  "manufacturer": "OnePlus"
 },
 "application": {
  "packageName": "com.google.android.gms",
  "version": "1"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is meaning of a dataStreamId

dataStreamId is a property that includes a unique identifier- a set of numbers. This is your developer project number, and it will be the same for all requests made using that particular developer account. More of that [here](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/data-sources#create_a_data_source).